# Advanced Rest Client saved requests / history missing

Tags: advanced-rest-client

I have Advanced Rest Client plug-in installed and am running macOS Mojave.
My machine had re-started and now all of my history / saved projects in ARC is now missing.
How can I get it back?

Chrome Version 81.0.4044.129 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Do you have a single application installed or both chrome plugin and desktop client? They are technically two different application that do not share data between them. Otherwise you can try restarting Chrome (cmd+q) as maybe there's a problem there.

Comment: restarting chrome / arc hasn't had any affect...I use chrome plugin (which opens the app)

Comment: It's hard to say what is happening. I am the author of the app. You can contact me on GitHub (ion the app you have an option to report an issue).